# Twilio adding more questions to phone poll example

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

In Twilio they have an example on a "phone poll" in php.
The phone poll has the following files, make call.php, poll.php, and process_poll.php.
Make call php - contains the SID etc and dials the call.
poll php - contains the actual poll question in a Gather tag.
As shown here:

```
<?php
require 'Services/Twilio.php';
$response = new Services_Twilio_Twiml();
$gather = $response->gather(array(
    'action' => 'php url to hit',
    'method' => 'GET',
    'numDigits' => '1'
));
$gather->say("Hi question one here");
$gather->say("From 1 to 5 with 5 being the best service.  How would you rate?");

header('Content-Type: text/xml');
print $response;
?>
```

process poll php contains the next step after they choose a selection. For sake of space I won't post the db area just what follows.

```
if (isset($choices[$digit])) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `results` (`" . $choices[$digit] . "`) VALUES ('1')");
    $say = 'Ok got it.  Next question.';
} else {
    $say = "Sorry, I don't have that option.  Next question.";
}
// @end snippet
// @start snippet

$response = new Services_Twilio_Twiml();
$response->say($say);
$response->hangup();
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
print $response;
```

my question on this is how would I add additional questions.  What currently happens is user hears first question.  Selects option from phone pad. Connection ends after a message response to their answer.  I would like to add about 3 more questions and then responses.  How can this be accomplished? Would I add a response that sends them to another url for the 2nd set of questions?

Can you please give me some guidance on how this could be accomplished? I'm a php novice.

Comment: You should ask each question in a separate URL, like that you can evaluate the answer to each individually.

Answer (score 0):

Ricky from Twilio here.

Great question. There are a few different ways you could build this. The method you outlined of having a separate URL for each question and response would absolutely work. In this scenario, `poll.php` would become `poll1.php`:

```
<?php
require 'Services/Twilio.php';
$response = new Services_Twilio_Twiml();
$gather = $response->gather(array(
    'action' => 'php url to hit',
    'method' => 'GET',
    'numDigits' => '1'
));
$gather->say("Hi question one here");
$gather->say("From 1 to 5 with 5 being the best service.  How would you rate?");

header('Content-Type: text/xml');
print $response;
?>
```

You would want to process this to `process_poll1.php`:

```
if (isset($choices[$digit])) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `results` (`" . $choices[$digit] . "`) VALUES ('1')");
    $say = 'Ok got it.  Next question.';
} else {
    $say = "Sorry, I don't have that option.  Next question.";
}
// @end snippet
// @start snippet

$response = new Services_Twilio_Twiml();
$response->say($say);
$response->redirect("php url to hit for next question");
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
print $response;
```

There's one key change besides the name I've changed in this file. We're going to use the  [TwiML verb](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/redirect) to move the user to the next poll question instead of hanging up. To do this with code we replace `$response->hangup();` with `$response->redirect("php url to hit for next question");`. You'd want this to redirect to `poll2.php` and then have the gather action on that go to `process_poll2.php`. Then continue for as many questions as you need.

Let me know if that helps!